# Could not clear the obstacle_layer of costmap_2d package in ros hydro

Tags: ros, navigation, roshydro, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have followed the navigation tutorial for ros hydro [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/83471/layered-costmap-problem/) and [other link](http://answers.ros.org/question/83031/move_base-and-costmap_layers/). I can see the obstacles are updated in the obstacle_layer. However the "clearing observation" task is not clear enough. For example, When I move in an move out the laser field of view, there are still several points can not be removed.
Here is [the link](http://postimg.org/image/u5w57r2hb/) picture of obstacle_layer
Did anyone have same problem before?

Here are my jaml and launch:
Costmap_common_params

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.225,-0.225],[-0.225,0.225], [0.225, 0.225], [0.225,-0.225]]
#robot_radius: 0.225
inflation_radius: 0.55
obstacle_layer:
observation_sources: laser
laser: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true, inf_is_valid: true}
```

Local_costmap_params

```
local_costmap:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 5.0
static_map: false
rolling_window: true
width: 6.0
height: 6.0
resolution: 0.01
 plugins:
  - {name: footprint_layer, type: "costmap_2d::FootprintLayer"} 
  - {name: obstacle_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer" }
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

Global_costmap_params

```
global_costmap:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
update_frequency: 5.0
static_map: true
plugins:
- {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
```

Move_base

```
enter code here
<!-- -->
<launch>
<!-- Run the map server -->
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find robot_platform)/maps/map.yaml" output="screen" clear_params="true"/>
<include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch" >
</include>
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
<rosparam file="$(find robot_platform)/params/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find robot_platform)/params/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find robot_platform)/params/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find robot_platform)/params/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find robot_platform)/params/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172762/could-not-clear-the-obstacle_layer-of-costmap_2d-package-in-ros-hydro/) by [tl20003](https://answers.ros.org/users/5089/tl20003/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-06-05**:
Hi ,tl20003 ,I am coming across the same problem with you now .And I have tried almost all the ways that proposed by others,but in vain.Have you worked out the problem?

**Comment by [tl20003](https://answers.ros.org/users/5089/tl20003/) on 2014-06-08**:
Hi, Yuichi, Have you solved that problem? I think our case is similar to this problem (http://answers.ros.org/question/30014/costmap-clearing-of-obstacles/). DimitriProsser suggested that we should use filter for laser scanner. However I did not check it by now.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-13**:
Can you clarify what obstacles you want removed and why you want them removed, please?

**Comment by [tl20003](https://answers.ros.org/users/5089/tl20003/) on 2014-06-16**:
Thanks David for your updating the post!
The story is that,
(1) I configure the navigation package using the jaml and launch file above
(2) Then I run the program
(3) I move around the laser field of view.
Normally, when I move form one position to other position the program should clear the obstacles "laser points" from previous position. However as you can see in the picture, there are still several "laser points". That points are maintained until when I stop program.

**Comment by [tl20003](https://answers.ros.org/users/5089/tl20003/) on 2014-06-16**:
According to DimitriProsser suggestion. I also used the range filter for laser data to remove the "inf", "nan" points. However I got the same result. What should I do to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I understand what you're saying; correct me if I'm wrong.

The navstack will only remove an obstacle from the costmap if there is a clearing observation that will remove it. Simply moving the obstacle will not remove it if there is no clearing observation.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tl20003](https://answers.ros.org/users/5089/tl20003/) on 2014-06-17**:
Thanks David. It is not totally true. I still do not know what is the reason. In my case, the navstack can remove the moving obstacles from the costmap. However, it did not remove clearly. Several points were still remained as you can see in the area "After move out the laser field of view" in the picture that I linked above.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-17**:
Can you add another picture with the sensor data visualized, before and after the move. Also, just to be specific, what is moving? The robot or the obstacle?

**Comment by [tl20003](https://answers.ros.org/users/5089/tl20003/) on 2014-06-17**:
Hi David, In my case the robot is stable and the obstacle is moving.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-06-24**:
Are you also able to add another picture?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using a REP 117 compliant laser/driver, like the hokuyo_node, you must use navigation +1.11.5 and pass the inf_is_valid param to your global and local costmap configuration. Otherwise, when the laser doesn't see anything you'll have +Inf, and they're not converted from LaserScan to PC in the costmap_2d code, and consequently nothing is cleared.

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tl20003](https://answers.ros.org/users/5089/tl20003/) on 2014-06-17**:
Thanks Enrique, I will check and let you know.